# Do the word 場当たり and ゲネプロ similar in their meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

[image]

This is from the twitter of a stage actor. He supposed to perform for a show in the next day, so I assumed

> 場当たり was from 場当たり稽古 = dress rehearsal​

but the word ゲネ also seems to derive from

> ゲネ = ゲネプロ dress rehearsal​

I was wondering if these words really mean the same? or whether they have any significant difference?

Comment: Today, he ended ‘場当たり’ n he’s having rehearsal ‘tomorrow’. Why don’t u think they are different meaning before you question?

Comment: @Wataru'Watson'Subridge That is why I'm asking the question in the first play? If I thought they mean the same, I would not have ask?

Answer (score 2):

No, they have different meanings. (From experience performing in a local opera group...)

Typically rehearsals are held in some nondescript room somewhere, with a mockup of the set. Then (in this case the day) before the performance (本番) the actual set is ready in the theatre, and the actors have to finalise positioning under the director's supervision: this is 場当たり. They might run through any "action" scenes, but there is no singing or acting as such. The next stage is the dress rehearsal, which is a straight run through without stopping (normally, at least). So in this case the actors now have an image of how they will perform on the actual set, in tomorrow's GP.

I think 場当たり稽古 would mean the same as 場当たり, which is a sort of rehearsal; but it is quite distinct from the dress rehearsal, which can be called ゲネ, or ゲーペー, the German pronunciation of "GP", since it comes from *Generalprobe*.

The dictionary definitions of 場当たり suggest it is about adapting to a new location, so perhaps the origin is in the world of travelling players.

Comment: By the way, I think リハーサル in Japanese normally refers to a run-through without stopping (but can be done in a nondescript room without lights, etc). Do you agree?